# How to handle directories or files using OptionParser

Tags: ruby, optparse

I find my self doing this often:

```
optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  options[:directory] = "/tmp/"
  opts.on('-d','--dir DIR', String, 'Directory to put the output in.') do |x|
    raise "No such directory" unless File.directory?(x)
    options[:directory] = x
  end
end
```

It would be nicer if I could specify `Dir` or `Pathname` instead of `String`.  Is there a pattern or my Ruby-esque way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure OptionParser to accept (for instance) a Pathname

```
require 'optparse'
require 'pathname'

OptionParser.accept(Pathname) do |pn|
  begin
    Pathname.new(pn) if pn
    # code to verify existence
  rescue ArgumentError
    raise OptionParser::InvalidArgument, s
  end
end
```

Then you can change your code to

```
opts.on('-d','--dir DIR',Pathname, 'Directory to put the output in.') do |x|
```

Comment: Thanks! That not only answers my question but gives a good example of how to extend optparse to accept more things!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Ruby-esque way of doing that, I would recommend to give [Trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org/) a try.

Since version 1.1o you can use the `:io` type which accepts a filename, URI, or the strings `stdin` or `-`.

```
require 'trollop'
opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :source, "Source file (or URI) to print",
      :type => :io,
      :required => true
end
opts[:source].each { |l| puts "> #{l.chomp}" }
```

If you need the pathname, then it is not what you are looking for. But if you are looking to read the file, then it is a powerful way to abstract it.

Comment: I didn't know about trollop. Neat!  I was looking for optparse specific answers, but I'll look at that in the future. :-)